# List of contacts using physical memory

Tags: java, android-studio

I need to build android app, and one of her features is activity that allow to the users to adding persons to their contact list.
I don't want to use server at all, i just want to add people to contact list and use the physical memory of the phone.
Thanks

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to do that?
How using the phisycal memory of the phone throgh android studio